# Looking to convert a Simple SVN tool to Git

Tags: git, bash, svn, bitbucket

So the purpose of the tool is to pull a static file that we use in each release to track SOX information.

Here is the code I used to use:

```bash
FirstOfYear=`date +%Y-01-01`
Today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

StartDate=${FirstOfYear}
EndDate=${Today}

# Change these for the app (as it appears in SVN) and the Code for the file names
app=FooApp
code=FA

# Clean up last Run
rm ${code}_*.txt
rm TT${code}_*.txt
#Setup the Header
last="0.0"
echo "${code} Releases ${StartDate} - ${EndDate}" >> TT${code}_Release_List.txt

for Release in `svn log -v --revision {${StartDate}}:{${EndDate}}   http://svn.mynet.com/repos/${app}/tags |grep "A /tags" | sed 's/.*gs\/\([0-9|.]*\).*/\1/g'`
do
 if [ ${last} != ${Release} ]; then

        svn export http://svn.mynet.com/repos/${app}/tags/"$Release"/docs/release_notes.txt ${code}_"$Release"_release_notes.txt
        cat ${code}_"$Release"_release_notes.txt | ./../GenSummary.pl >> ${code}_Summary.txt
        cat ${code}_"$Release"_release_notes.txt | ./../GenReleaseList.pl >> TT${code}_Release_List.txt
        echo http://svn.mynet.com/repos/${app}/tags/"$Release"/docs/release_notes.txt >> ${code}_Summary.txt
        echo ================================================= >> ${code}_Summary.txt

 fi
 last=$Release

done
```

So just to explain...this script simply looks through the SVN repository between the dates specified and pulls the Tag's that where created then.  It then pulls the key file from the repository.

We have/are migrating to Git and we are using the [git-workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow) so in the end of the cycle we have a group of tags on the master branch.

Now I *think* that the only way I can pull off the same stuff I did for SVN is to clone repository so I can then poll it for information...

Anyone have any other suggestions? By the way, we are using Bitbucket for our central repository.

Comment: yeah, you'll most likely have to clone the repo, although if all your release files are in the master branch that should make things easy from that point.

Comment: Yeah, I have been looking at git archive and git checkout-index  but I can't seem to get it to check out just one file from the repos.. 

do you have any suggestions for checking out tags that fall in a date range..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got a working solution. Of course, you'll have to clone the repo locally first, then from within the repo do something like this:

```
FirstOfYear=`date +%Y-01-01`
Today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

StartDate=${FirstOfYear}
EndDate=${Today}

for commit in `git tag --list |xargs git show --since=$StartDate --before=$EndDate --format='COMMIT: %H'|grep 'COMMIT: '|cut -d' ' -f2`; do
    git show $commit:docs/release_notes.txt >> /tmp/output_file
done
```

Here's a breakdown of that ugly mess in the `for` loop:

1: List all the tags:

```
git tag --list
```

2: Pass all those tags to `git show`, filter out everything not in the dates you're looking for, and print out the commit with the prefix `COMMIT:`

```
xargs git show --since=$StartDate --before=$EndDate --format='COMMIT: %H'
```

3: parse out just the commit hashes from that output

```
grep 'COMMIT: '|cut -d' ' -f2`
```

Now we have a list of the commits that were tagged in the date range you wanted and we can use `git cat-file` to dump out the `release_notes.txt` of each tag.

You should be able to add in any other special processing you need.

**---EDIT---**

If you need the tag name in the name of the output file you can do the following:

```
FirstOfYear=`date +%Y-01-01`
Today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

StartDate=${FirstOfYear}
EndDate=${Today}

for tag_and_commit in `git tag --list |xargs git show --since=$StartDate --before=$EndDate|perl -ne '$_=join("", <>); while(/^tag (\w+).*?^commit (\w+)/gsm) { print "$1-$2\n" }'`; do
    IFS='-' read -r -a ARR <<< "$tag_and_commit"
    tag=${ARR[0]}
    commit=${ARR[1]}
    git show $commit:docs/release_notes.txt >> /tmp/$tag-output_file
done
```

Note that this is getting really ugly to do all of this in a bash script (probably in part due to my weak bash skills). Might be better long term to convert this to a perl/ruby/whatever script.

Comment: This is a Great solution, but I am having trouble with one part.  I really would like to get the name of the file I am outputing too to be named with the Tag I am pulling the hash for.

every time I try to break apart #1 and #2 I end up with only #1

Comment: I edited the answer with a version that does this. Sorry it's a bit ugly.